# Amazon Glacier - Retrieval of files base on prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Your suggestions will be of great help for my project.

Planning to use Amazon glacier to store a cron job's output for long term storage. Cron Job output will be generated on daily basis & each file will be in this below name format

```
03-04-2017-output-1.txt
03-04-2017-output-2.txt
04-04-2017-output-1.txt
04-04-2017-output-2.txt
```

Is it possible to retrieve a single file which is a consolidation of files with a date prefix?
For example, I want to retrieve files generated on 03-04-2017, so one single zip file containing 03-04-2017-output-1.txt, 03-04-2017-output-2.txt
Is it possible to select files based on file names and retrieve?

I visited the documents of AWS amazon glacier and understood the about range retrieval which based on MB, is it possible to retrieve based on filename ?

Comment: DON'T USE GLACIER unless you are pretty sure what you are doing.   
Looking at the way on how you retrieve the file, I bet you really don't know the hidden cost behind glacier.   Make a estimation on your storage need, then read the S3 pricing on standard and IA.  
It is nice to learn other people "lesson" as show here -->  https://medium.com/@karppinen/how-i-ended-up-paying-150-for-a-single-60gb-download-from-amazon-glacier-6cb77b288c3e

Comment: Hi @mootmoot , Thanks for your warning ..will keep in mind about the Amazon glacier upload & download costs.. Still we chose glacier for long term storage and not for frequent access.. just wanted to know whether this mode of consolidating files based on file names while retrieving is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned file store inside the zip file, it is really irrelevant to all storage services, because digging into ZIP contents is a waste of CPU resources and a high risk practice (e.g. archive bomb/zip bomb).

So you need to deal directly with the object stored.

IMHO, your best bet is create your [S3 storage inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). As long as you make sure your zipped log file are given proper date/etc index prefix/suffix.  This is also useful if you want to store mid-term contents inside S3 standard and standard-IA storage as well.

As mentioned by [AWS Glacier FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/)

> Q: Can I see what archives I have stored in Amazon Glacier?
>
> Yes. Although you will need to maintain your own index of data you
>   upload to Amazon Glacier, an inventory of all archives in each of your
>   vaults is maintained for disaster recovery or occasional
>   reconciliation purposes. The vault inventory is updated approximately
>   once a day. You can request a vault inventory as either a JSON or CSV
>   file and will contain details about the archives within your vault
>   including the size, creation date and the archive description (if you
>   provided one during upload). The inventory will represent the state of
>   the vault at the time of the most recent inventory update.